# "_Problem loading widget" ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview

I have a `ImageView` in my `widget` and i am updating the source of the `ImageView` by using

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imHour0, R.drawable.time_0);
```

But the widget is showing me error `"Problem Loading Widget"`. Also i cannot see any error in my `Logcat` so i am clueless about what wrong am i doing. When i remove that line the widget loads perfectly thus there is something wrong in that particular code. `time_0` is the default image that appears on the widget but even if i try to set that image i get the error.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the layout xml for the widget. Does it still fail if you don't set that image?

Comment: @NeilTownsend No it shows correctly if i didn't update the image. The xml is very big since it consist of nested `LinearLayouts`. Do you want complete xml of just ImageView Part?

Comment: How big? If you don't feel you can put it up here, could you put it somewhere? I can't really comment further until I've seen it ...

Comment: @NeilTownsend where should i paste it? Pastebin.com seems to be down

Comment: @NeilTownsend here is the xml http://pastie.org/private/lbp5rte44eoxisj8yjabxg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is either a typo in the question, the xml or your code. In the xml, you have:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivHour0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/time_0" />
```

But when you change the image:

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.imHour0, R.drawable.time_0);
```

Which should be (to match the id in the xml):

```
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivHour0, R.drawable.time_0);
                                 ^letter wrong
```

I guess you have an `imHour0` elsewhere, so it appears to be error free, but it isn't actually in the widget, so when it tries to change the image for that `id` it fails.

Comment: It's strange I set `imHour0` id to ImageView during the initial project creation. Then i realized i did it wrong and changed it to `ivHour0` couple of days back. But I am getting both id's in my suggestions. Do you have any idea as why i am getting `imHours0` as well since i replaced that id with `ivHour0` and it isn't in any of my xml?

Comment: The auto-complete suggestions tend to acquire options but not lose them! I'm not an expert in that area, but I have noticed the same thing! Did this solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it did. I was waiting for your reply before marking your answer. From now i will be more careful and learn from this mistake as well. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is no method like `setImageViewResource(int resourse)`
use this it would help you:

```
views.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_0);
```

Comment: how would view know in which imageView i want to set that image without providing a ID? I have more ImageViews in whom i want to set Images.

Comment: you can make an array of imageviews. views[index].setImageResource(R.drawable.time_0)

Comment: I am using a Widget and referencing to ImageView using RemoteViews so there is no function like `setImageViewResource(int resourse)` instead we have a function `views.setImageViewResource(int viewID, int srcId)`